# React Router on the list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

After clicking users name in album section should appear list of albums and url should be like this http://localhost:3000/users/1 ->(http://localhost:3000/users/:id) but when I put my {user.name} into Link I don't receive the id (without Link I have the correct id) where should I write my Route for list item for getting correct url?
 [image]

[image]

The full version is in the https://github.com/MarineKh/React-Router

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `li` with `Link`

```
<Link to={'/users/${user.id}'}>
  <li>${user.name}</li>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

The natural approach here is to leverage the router to capture the parameter e.g.

```
<Route path="/users/:id" components={Albums} />
```

And then you can access the parameter from the props

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Finally, if this is React Router v4 then you need to wrap your container with the `withRouter` HOC in order to bind those params i.e.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Albums extends Component {
   ...
}
export default withRouter(Albums)
```

Comment: Is it right where I write my Route? or should I use it inside my UserList.js too?